# Spring Boot - lettuce-core and netty issue: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/netty/util/Recycler$EnhancedHandle

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, netty, lettuce, elastic-cache

Could you please give any insight about how to solve it this error?
The error popped up when I changed the version of aws to 2.20.161.

`Unable to connect to [cache]: Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/netty/util/Recycler$EnhancedHandle aws.sdk.version -> 2.20.161 lettuce-core -> 6.1.9.RELEASE</version use internally netty -> 4.1.79.Final.`

I've change the lettuce-core version to 6.1.9.RELEASE, It solved another error but popped up anther one.